# Add delay before repeat animation with valueAnimator

Tags: android

I'm trying a simple example like having a `TextView` and   translate it from 0% to 100% of the screen width

code is :

```
    anim0  = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textViewId00, "translationX", -120f, 480f);
```

where 480f is the width of my screen.

What I want is the next N  times  ( n=5 for my example ) to add a delay before it starts.

I have tried to add the delay with `setStartDelay()` method on `onAnimationRepeat` but there is no effect.

My code is :

```
        textViewId00 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId00);


    anim0  = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textViewId00, "translationX", -120f, 480f);
    anim0.setDuration(2000);
    anim0.setRepeatCount(5);
    anim0.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "anim0 onAnimationStart ");
            textViewId00.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "anim0 onAnimationEND " );
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "anim0 onAnimation REPEAT " );
            anim0.setStartDelay(14000);
        }
    });
    anim0.start();
```

The textView appears to the screen, moves until it disappears and  then again from start without any delay.

Comment: Could you set the animation to not repeat and add an anim0.start() inside the onAnimationEnd of the listener, perhaps?

Comment: Then it will not enter `onAnimationRepeat`. Just tried it and nothing happens.

Comment: Do you want it to animate off the screen, pause, appear back in its original position after a delay and animate off again?

Comment: yes that's what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just tried it using this code and it looks like it is doing what you want it to:

```
public void animateView() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    final int screenWidth = size.x;

    final ObjectAnimator anim0  = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textviewId00, "translationX", -120f, screenWidth);
    anim0.setDuration(2000);
    anim0.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

        int count;

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            textViewId00.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            if (++count < 5) {
                anim0.setStartDelay(14000);
                anim0.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
    anim0.start();
}
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you. Although I can't understand what is wrong with my approach.

Comment: Suppose I want to repeat the animation right away after that, forever, what should I do in the onAnimationEnd ?

Comment: how to cancel it