# How to restart object animator after some seconds in Android?

Tags: android, objectanimator

My code looks like that:

```
objectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0f, (float) truePosition);
        animator.setDuration(totalTime);
        animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                einsatz = 0;
                disableChips();
                imageRoulette.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                imageRoulette.setEnabled(true);
                imageRoulette.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageRoulette.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roulette);

                enableChips();
                printNumberAfterRotation(randPosition);
                myBets.clear();
                einsatz = -1;
                gesamtEinsatz = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) { }
});
animator.start();
```

By now I always have to tap on the view to rotate my image. Is there a way to restart it after 10 seconds?
Do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);

Comment: I want to start it after 10 seconds break so how can I fix that?

Comment: remove animation.setRepeatCount  and add setStartDelay(millisec) inside AnimationEnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                animation.setStartDelay(10000); // 10 SEC
                animation.start();
            }
```

Comment: OR   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880981/add-delay-before-repeat-animation-with-valueanimator